# Azure WebApps React: the environment variables exist but are not present when I call process.env

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure-web-app-service

## Prerequisite

this is my first usage of React/Node.JS/Azure App Service. I usually deploy apps using flask/jinja2/gunicorn.

## The use case

I would like to use the environment variables stored in the **Configuration** of my App **Service on Azure**

Unfortunately, **the environment variables displays 3 environment variables (NODE_END, PUBLIC_URL and FAST_REFRESH) instead of several dozens**.

### The partial content of the Azure App Service **appsettings**

```json
[
{
    "name": "REACT_APP_APIKEY",
    "value": "some key",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "REACT_APP_APPID",
    "value": "an app id",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "REACT_APP_AUTHDOMAIN",
    "value": "an auth domain",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
{
    "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
    "value": "something",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING",
    "value": "something else",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION",
    "value": "some alphanumeric value",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "KUDU_EXTENSION_VERSION",
    "value": "78.11002.3584",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
]
```

[image: environment variables on Azure Web App]

## The CI/CD process

1. I am using Azure DevOps to build and deploy the app on Azure.
2. The process runs `npm install` and `npm run build` before generating the zip file containing the build (see the **directory tree list** here below)

## How do I Run the App?

The **startup command** contains `npx serve -l 8080 .`

[image: Azure Web App Service - Configuration > General Settings]

## The Issue

I display the environment variables with

```js
console.log('process.env', process.env);
```

The content of the `process.env` is

```json
{
  "NODE_ENV": "production",
  "PUBLIC_URL": "",
  "FAST_REFRESH": true
}
```

## The Wired part

I use SSH on Azure and I run

`printenv | grep APPINS` the result is

```
APPSETTING_APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY=something
APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY=something
```

`printenv | grep APPLICATION` the result is

```
APPSETTING_APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING=something else
APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING=something else
```

## Misc

### Directory Tree list

```
.
├── asset-manifest.json
├── favicon.ico
├── images
│   ├── app
│   │   └── home_page-ott-overthetop-platform.png
│   ├── films
│   │   ├── children
│   │   │   ├── despicable-me
│   │   │   │   ├── large.jpg
│   │   │   │   └── small.jpg
│   ├── icons
│   │   ├── add.png
│   ├── misc
│   │   ├── home-bg.jpg
│   ├── series
│   │   ├── children
│   │   │   ├── arthur
│   │   │   │   ├── large.jpg
│   │   │   │   └── small.jpg
│   └── users
│       ├── 1.png
├── index.html
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── 2.679831fc.chunk.css
│   │   └── 2.679831fc.chunk.css.map
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── 2.60c35184.chunk.js
│   │   ├── 2.60c35184.chunk.js.LICENSE.txt
│   │   ├── 2.60c35184.chunk.js.map
│   │   ├── main.80f5c16d.chunk.js
│   │   ├── main.80f5c16d.chunk.js.map
│   │   ├── runtime-main.917a28e7.js
│   │   └── runtime-main.917a28e7.js.map
│   └── media
│       └── logo.623fc416.svg
└── videos
    └── bunny.mp4

74 directories, 148 files
```

Comment: Did you see if the react app environment variable needs to be in a manner of REACT_APP_ <name of your variable>

Comment: Dear @yatin-gaikwad, YES I do use `REACT_APP_`  as a prefix of the variables.

I have edited the JSON containing the appsettings at the beginning of the question.

Comment: You need to mention server.js or index.js file which starts node server.

Comment: Hi, did you get a solution to this? I am not a fan of using the .env file on production as suggested by others

Comment: process.env is set within the server as of `npm run build`. In most cases I've seen, they set configuration variables during the build.

Answer (score -4):

When you run your application locally, you could use `.env` file to config your environment variables. Format like "`name=value`"(without quotes).
Here is a sample:

```
REACT_APP_APIKEY=REACT_APP_APIKEY
REACT_APP_APPID=REACT_APP_APPID
REACT_APP_AUTHDOMAIN=REACT_APP_AUTHDOMAIN
```

When I call `console.log('process.env', process.env);` in index.js file, it works well:

[image]

After configuring the app settings on portal, deploy the nodejs web app to Azure.

You can view log output (calls to console.log) from the app directly in the VS Code output window. Just right-click the app node and choose **Start Streaming Logs** in the **AZURE APP SERVICE** explorer.

It shows the environment variables on portal Application settings:

[image]

---

By the way:

1. If you are very new to use node with Azure web app, you could have a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?pivots=platform-windows
2. About how to use `.env` file, see this: https://holycoders.com/node-js-environment-variable/

Comment: User was asking about runtime environment variables. For example he want to change an api key without rebuilding and deploying. Having it on .env files doesn't help in that case