# Azure Static Web App NodeJS env variables

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, environment-variables, azure-pipelines

I'm using Azure Static Web App service and Azure DevOps pipeline to deploy a NodeJS app. The pipeline and the build are going well. Now i have to define a URL for the backend using env variables, but without success.

```
trigger:
- develop

jobs:
  - job: JobTest
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest

    variables:
    - name: BACKEND_URL
      value: https://<some_url>
    - name: System.Debug
      value: true
    steps:
    - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
      inputs:
        app_location: "/" 
        api_location: ""
        output_location: "dist"

      env:
        BACKEND_URL: $(BACKEND_URL)
        azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(deployment_token)
    - bash: echo $(BACKEND_URL)
    - bash: echo $PWD
```

and from the NodeJS code, in the "/app/src/models/config.ts" file i have the this:

> export const BACKEND_URL = process.env.BACKEND_URL

If i change **process.env.BACKEND_URL** with the actual URL it will work.

Also, from the Azure Pipeline this task is using the https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx build system.

The question is how can i use env from the pipeline in the code?

Comment: I don’t think the task supports additional environment variables right now. Created an issue here to fix https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/392

Answer (score 2):

**Static Web App cannot use back end variables.**

You could consider using `.env` file to config your environment variables. Format like "`name=value`"(without quotes).

And install `dotenv` in the file you want to invoke the environment variables, access them by `process.env`.

Have a look at this article: [Node.js Environment Variable Configuration by using env file](https://holycoders.com/node-js-environment-variable/)

And my another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67052708/13586071

Comment: That is how is set up. But i guess its not working with the static app as @Anthony Chu point out. I have `.env.sample` file in `/app/build/` directory. And also i have the bash script `cp ./build/.env.sample .env` to be executed from the `package.json` file in `/app/` directory. Locally works ok but when i try to build it with Azure Pipeline im getting error that the file does not exists. So that is why i put the variable in the env and its there but its never render like that or set it up.

Comment: @IvanAK I have a same problem. Did you find any solutions?

Comment: @M Karimi I didn't find any solutions, till that time if i remember good, was that if you bild and deply like that with that kind of pipeline and directly to web app it makes a problem. Other pipelines or applications dont have it. Try using GitHub actions and work flows

Answer (score 2):

To help improve this issue, I have added an answer:

the env variables cannot be used azure pipeline with azure Static Web App. And [here is a ticket which reports the issue](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/392).