# React app hosted as Static WebApp on Azure doesn't detect env vars

Tags: node.js, reactjs, environment-variables, azure-pipelines, azure-static-web-app

I have a YAML task for deploying a static web app:

```
- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    name: DeployStaticWebApp
    displayName: Deploy Static Web App
    inputs:
      app_location: 'web-app'
      app_build_command: 'npm ci && npm run build:int'
      cwd: '${{ parameters.root }}/webapp_package'
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(deployment_token)
    env:
      REACT_APP_AAD_UI_APP_CLIENT_ID: $(REACT_APP_AAD_UI_APP_CLIENT_ID)
      REACT_APP_AAD_API_APP_CLIENT_ID: $(REACT_APP_AAD_API_APP_CLIENT_ID)
      REACT_APP_AAD_APP_TENANT_ID: $(REACT_APP_AAD_APP_TENANT_ID)
      REACT_APP_AAD_APP_SERVICE_BASE_URI: $(REACT_APP_AAD_APP_SERVICE_BASE_URI)
```

I have a package.json with scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",    
    "start:int": "env-cmd -f .env.int npm start",    
    "build": "react-scripts build",    
    "build:int": "env-cmd -f .env.int npm run-script build",   
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

How do I pass the following env values during build/deployment?

```
      REACT_APP_AAD_UI_APP_CLIENT_ID: $(REACT_APP_AAD_UI_APP_CLIENT_ID)
      REACT_APP_AAD_API_APP_CLIENT_ID: $(REACT_APP_AAD_API_APP_CLIENT_ID)
      REACT_APP_AAD_APP_TENANT_ID: $(REACT_APP_AAD_APP_TENANT_ID)
      REACT_APP_AAD_APP_SERVICE_BASE_URI: $(REACT_APP_AAD_APP_SERVICE_BASE_URI)
```